# Grouping Pivot Table Values/Metrics/Calculated Fields into one Field to put in report filter

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

Say I wanted to group all my metrics that I have in my values in my pivot table(including all added calculated fields) into one field to be able to use in the Report Filter.

So I want all those values in a drop down to be able to select a metric and it populates my pivot table below.

Is that possible with VBA Code? Am I explaining clearly?